# Initialize Kivy widget values from Python on program start

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I am trying to initialize some values of widgets in Kivy on program start, with no success. Simplified Python code is:

```
inital_text = "init text"

class MainApp(App):

    def initialize_widgets(self):
        self.root.ids.my_label.text = initial_text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
    MainApp.initialize_widgets(App)
```

And the relevant piece from kv file is:

```
Label:
    id: my_label
    text: "default text"
```

When I run the program, the label says "default text". When quitting it, I get the error:

```
line 5, in initialize_widgets
self.root.ids.my_label.text = initial_text
AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'root'
```

I have tried other workarounds, some quite desperate ones, with no success.

Comment: Why would your root have a root? Change to `self.ids.my_label.text`

Comment: @pstatix I have tried this as well. In that case I get errror "AttributeError: type object 'MainApp' has no attribute 'ids'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *on_start* event to initialize the label's text on program start. In the example below, a *Clock.schedule_once* event was added to show the initial value and then the change.

## Note

In this example, the root widget is *Label* widget (*root*) and the root's dictionary (root.ids) is empty. If there is another widget with `id: my_textinput`, added as children of the root then root's dictionary will contain one id i.e. *my_textinput*. A `print(self.root.ids)` will demonstrate this.

*self* - The keyword self references the “current widget instance” i.e. App.

[Kivy Language » ids](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#ids)

> When the kv file is processed, weakrefs to all the widgets tagged with ids are added to the root widget’s ids dictionary.

## Snippets

```
from kivy.app import App


initial_text = "init text"


class MainApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.text = initial_text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock

initial_text = "init text"


class MainApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.initialize_widgets, 5)

    def initialize_widgets(self, dt):
        self.root.text = initial_text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Label's text changed]

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I also appreciate the clear examples.